# Add icon to WPF TreeViewItem at runtime

Tags: .net, wpf, treeview, icons, treeviewitem

There are many samples demonstrating this in XAML, such as the following:

```
<TreeViewItem>
<TreeViewItem.Header>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
<Image Source="..."/>
<TextBlock>Hello</TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
</TreeViewItem.Header>

</TreeViewItem>
```

But I need to do this in runtime code - the purpose of TreeView is to show files and folders on the computer.

So I'm not sure how to work with Header in code:

```
 For Each f In directory.GetFiles()

        Dim icon = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(f.FullName)
        Dim name As String = f.Name    

        Dim item As New TreeViewItem
         item.Header = ...


 Next
```

Can anyone demonstrate the concept please?

**EDIT:** I think I'm getting it, I should use horizontal StackPanel with two separate controls - TextBlock and Image. Is this the right approach?

Answer (score 2):

.

Here is the sample code as to how you should start. Understand this first, and then make appropriate change to meet your need. The code written in C# and XAML. Hope you'll understand C# and would be able to convert it to Basic.

```
    public class NameIconPair
    {
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public BitmapSource IconSource { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("E:\\");
            ObservableCollection<NameIconPair> pairs = new ObservableCollection<NameIconPair>();
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                System.Drawing.Icon icon = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(file);
                Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
                icon.Save(stream);
                BitmapDecoder decoder = IconBitmapDecoder.Create(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.None);
                BitmapSource src = decoder.Frames[0];
                pairs.Add(new NameIconPair() { Name = file,  IconSource = src });
            }
            this.DataContext = pairs;
        }
    }
```

And here is the XAML code:

```
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="{Binding IconSource}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

Hope, this sample code would help you greatly. :-)

.